# Using Marshmallow to serialize/deserialize with multiple formats

Tags: flask, marshmallow

I have a Flask web service with a REST API with requests that expect a user to be serialized in a specific format. In addition, the web service interacts with a 3rd party service that expects the user serialized in a different format.

Is it possible with Marshmallow to serialize/deserialize with different formats? If not, can I get suggestions on alternative implementations? Thanks.

The code below is a simplified example based off of the [Marshmallow documentation](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/quickstart.html).

```
import datetime as dt

class User(object):
    def __init__(self, name, email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.created_at = dt.datetime.now()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User(name={self.name!r})>'.format(self=self)
```

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

class UserSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    email = fields.Email()
    created_at = fields.DateTime()
```

```
api_user_data = {
  "name": "Alex Honnold",
  "email": "ah@example.com"
}
```

```
3rd_party_service_user_data = {
  "metadata": {
    "name": "Alex Honnold",
    "email": "ah@example.com"
  }
```

```
schema = UserSchema()
```

I'd like to deserialize by calling something like `schema.load()` on either of the `user_data` values and subsequently call `schema.dump()` to serialize into either of those values.

Comment: Perhaps creating new Schema `3rdPartyUserSchema` which defines nested `UserSchema` like this: `metadata = fields.Nested('UserSchema')` would resolve your issue?

Comment: @needtobe That's a good idea for this particular example. I failed to mention though that I stripped out a few differences between `api_user_data` and `3rd_party_service_user_data` for the sake of simplifying my question, which would make your suggested implementation not work. I'll edit my question to note this.

Comment: Use two different Schemas.